# How do I test a password string in android java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, passwords

I'm working on a project and currently testing simple logins and not regarding security measures just yet and I came across a problem, I can't compare a password input to a simple string the same way as a Username.

I looked everywhere but only security measures show up pretty much and I just wanted to know that how can I do this in a simpler way, with something similar to string comparison.

edit - It's still a volatile program I'm just testing methods and the function I made is this(Portuguese btw):

```
public void login_try(View view) {

    //Obter o nome de utilizador e transformar em string
    TextView name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    String nome = name.getText().toString();

    //Obter a password e transformar em string
    TextView password = findViewById(R.id.name);
    String palavra_passe = password.getText().toString();

    //Testa o nome e a password para dar login
    if (nome.equals("Rubas") && palavra_passe.equals("123")) {

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Entrou com sucesso!!!!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    } else {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Login falhado :(";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();


    }
}
```

Comment: What's the specific difference? A bit of code to illustrate the problem would also help

Comment: i hope the password is hashed in the DB, do the same with the password provided and then compare (string comparison) the 2 hashed passwords

Comment: I updated the question sorry

Comment: Which toast is being displayed?

Comment: @Garikai currently only the sencond one (failed) because of the password part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the problem is stemming from the `findViewById(R.id.name)` on the password `TextField` assignment; you should probably change that to refer to the password `TextField` (must be something like `TextField password = findViewById(R.id.password)`)

Comment: Thank you, I was hot-headed and it went completely over my head.

Comment: @rubas It happens man, just make sure you do a thorough review of your modules for such simple logical errors

Answer (score -1):

```
TextView password = findViewById(R.id.name);
```

you're telling that your password view is also the name, this type of logical errors are extremely easy to spot with a simple debug ;)